# Using R for next-generation sequencing vcf files

Tags: r, regex, bioinformatics, sequencing, vcf-variant-call-format

I am an R beginner. I am using R to analyse my large next-generation sequencing vcf file and am having some difficulties. I have imported the very large vcf file as a data frame (2446824 obs. of 177 variables) and made a subset with just the 3 samples I am interested in (2446824 obs. of 29 variables).

I now wish to reduce the dimensions even further (reduce the rows to around 200000). I have been trying to use grep, but cannot get it to work. The error I get is

```
Error in "0/1" | "1/0" : 
   operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

Here is a small example part of the file I am working with.

```
Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.refGene    INFO    FORMAT  Run.Sample1 Run.Sample2 Run.Sample3
489 1   909221  909221  T   C   PASS    GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1:11,0:11:33:0,33,381     ./.     ./.
490 1   909238  909238  G   C   PASS    GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1:11,6:17:99:171,0,274    0/1:6,5:11:99:159,0,116     1/1:0,15:15:36:441,36,0
491 1   909242  909242  A   G   PASS    GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1:16,4:13:45:0,45,532     0/0:11,0:11:30:0,30,366     0/0:16,0:17:39:0,39,479
492 1   909309  909309  T   C   PASS    GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/0:23,0:23:54:0,54,700     0/0:15,1:16:36:0,36,463     0/0:19,0:19:48:0,48,598
```

There are two different ways in which I would like to reduce the rows in this dataset:

Code 1. If either $Run.Sample1 or $Run.Sample2 or $Run.Sample3 contains a “0/1” or “1/0” or “1/1” keep the entire row

Code 2. If $Run.Sample1 or $Run.Sample2 contain either a “0/1” or “1/0” or “1/1” and $Run.Sample3 contain “0/0” keep the entire row

The results I would want to get from code 1 are:

```
Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.refGene    INFO    FORMAT  Run.Sample1 Run.Sample2 Run.Sample3
489 1   909221  909221  T   C   PASS    GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1:11,0:11:33:0,33,381     ./.     ./.
490 1   909238  909238  G   C   PASS    GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1:11,6:17:99:171,0,274    0/1:6,5:11:99:159,0,116     1/1:0,15:15:36:441,36,0
491 1   909242  909242  A   G   PASS    GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1:16,4:13:45:0,45,532     0/0:11,0:11:30:0,30,366     0/0:16,0:17:39:0,39,479
```

The results I would want to get from code 2 are:

```
Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.refGene    INFO    FORMAT  Run.Sample1 Run.Sample2 Run.Sample3
489 1   909221  909221  T   C   PASS    GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1:11,0:11:33:0,33,381     ./.     ./.
491 1   909242  909242  A   G   PASS    GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1:16,4:13:45:0,45,532     0/0:11,0:11:30:0,30,366     0/0:16,0:17:39:0,39,479
```

Many thanks for your help

Kelly

Comment: Welcome, Kelly. This question on [creating reproducible examples in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) may be of use to you in the future. In particular, using `dput` to provide a subset of your data, rather than plaintext, makes it much easier for others to quickly get working on the toy problem.

Comment: @voidHead - true, but in this case a simple `read.table` around the plaintext gets it done, so it's not as big a concern as it can be. Of more concern is probably the fact that the first 8 columns aren't really necessary at all.

Comment: Your second result seems wrong to me. The first row doesn't have sample 3 contain "0/0" at all.

Comment: Yeah, those results are wrong.  I just spent 20 minutes thinking I was wrong

Comment: It would be easiest on the brain and eyes to use `sapply(df[,tail(names(df), 3)], substring, 1, 3)` and `%in%`

Comment: @thelatemail I am very very sorry for the error. I have realised my error is in the description. Code 2. If $Run.Sample1 or $Run.Sample2 contain either a “0/1” or “1/0” or “1/1” and $Run.Sample3 contain “0/0” **or "./."** keep the entire row

Comment: There are many dedicated packages that work with VCF files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try
For the first case:

```
  dat[Reduce(`|`,lapply(dat[9:11], function(x) grepl("0/1|1/0|1/1", x))),]
```

For the second case based on the conditions mentioned:

```
 dat[ Reduce(`|`,lapply(dat[9:10], function(x) grepl("0/1|1/0|1/1", x))) 
              & grepl("0/0", dat[,11]),]
```

#### Update

```
 dat[ Reduce(`|`,lapply(dat[9:10], function(x) grepl("0/1|1/0|1/1", x))) 
       & grepl("\\.\\/\\.|0/0", dat[,11]),]
```

Comment: Nice. `dat[do.call(mapply, c(any, lapply(dat[9:11],grepl,pattern="0/1|1/0|1/1"))),]` was my attempt

Comment: It baffles me that you can whip this up so fast.  Very nice.

Comment: @Richard Scriven If you are referring to `Sockpuppets`, I give up on that.  Now, it is 100% genuine :-)

Comment: I don't even know what a SockPuppet is.  I'm not a programmer, just R.

Comment: @Richard Scriven.  It means creating multiple identities to deceive others.

Comment: @akrun, did you just admit creating them? I thought it was some mistake. Or you was just kidding...

Comment: @akrun Thank you so much. This worked perfectly for Code 1. Unfortunately I realised I made an error in the description of Code 2 (I have commented above with the additional **or "./."**. Thanks